# CountDownTimer Text dissapears if a different Activity opened - Timer continues - android app

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I have a countdowntimer that starts when a button is pressed.

Once you press the button - the button dims, and text on the button appears and counts down to 0 (when onFinish is reached the button becomes illuminated again and the text reads 'done').

I have a settings menu that allows for the addition of more timers and other settings - if a user starts a timer and it is working fine - then opens the settings menu and saves settings, they come back to the timer screen.

What they see is that the button is grayed out as if the timer is still counting down (which it is), but the text is no longer there counting down and when the timer finishes the button just remains dim.

Is there anyway to get the text counting down to be persistent in that activity even if another Activity is opened up temporarily (like the settings menu) so it will always show the appropriate timer countdown text?  I'm still very new to android programming so any examples are appreciated.

TimerCode looks something like this:

```
    //Timer Countdown
@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    button.setText((millisUntilFinished/1000)+"");
    button.getBackground().setColorFilter(android.graphics.Color.GRAY, Mode.MULTIPLY);
    button.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    button.setTextSize(24);
    //Timer Finishes
@Override
public void onFinish() {
    System.out.println("DONE");
    button.setTextSize(44);
    button.setText("UP");
    button.getBackground().setColorFilter(null);
```

Button Code looks like this:

```
        //Right Button1
    final CountDown rButton1Timer = new CountDown(300000,200,bRightButton1);
    bRightButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            rButton1Timer.start();

        }
    });
```

Ultimately I just want the onTick and onFinish to be persistent through whatever the user does - so if he opens up the settings and changes something, when he comes back to the timers they are still counting down.

Any ideas?

Comment: any advice on what to put in the onResume() ?  I'm struggling to find what I need - which is why I posted the question.  Thank you for the point in the right direction though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onResume was the culprit.  I have since implemented onResume with success.